# Are Secret, or Private, keys safe when authenticating through SSO?

Tags: security, single-sign-on

Where I work, Single Sign On to other applications is all the rage. However, when working on some code I inherited, I found that one of our third parties (a major company) uses a combination of a secret key, a timestamp and a userID to authenticate into their system. All of this information is passed through SSL over a query string (MD5 hash). My coworker and I discovered this and, since we had knowledge of how this (open source) SSO solution worked, we were able to simply generate our own query string and login to anyone's account without a password! Needless to say, we promptly squashed this SSO feature.

I'm not an expert on security by any means, but used this way, aren't secret keys such as this incredibly dangerous? Especially since the third party's SSO "connector" is open source. They recommend changing the key every so often, but like I said, this just seems way too easy to brute force into; guessing one password equals access to everyone's account! Please let me know your thoughts and opinions, enlighten me :)

Comment: md5 is not a method of encryption.

Comment: Hey Rook, woops didn't mean to imply that! That's actually what made me even MORE concerned about it.

Comment: I assume your private keys & public keys are encrypted with 512-bit RSA. It is NOT an easy task to break the keys unless both keys are totally exposed to public.

Comment: so you were able to figure out the secret key?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I'm not sure, the third party source isn't available, but their plugins are OSS.

Comment: @JasonS didn't realize there was a Security.SE, hopefully someone will move it :)

Answer (score 0):

Security level of SSO boils down to implementation of particular product. I am not a expert in SSO or security. But OpenID is a good option: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openid. And btw, StackOvewfloe is using OpenID as well.

Comment: Apart from OpenID, I will suggest to use Facebook SSO / Google SSO to give users a more friendly user experience.

Answer (score 0):

SSO is pretty save as long as the private keys stay private. The keys should be encrypted with 512-bit RSA or something and so it would be very hard to brute force. But if the private key and public are exposed then the whole system collapses and that's not only in SSO. Private keys should stay private and shouldn't be exposed to anyone. So I already wonder if the secret key in this case is the same as a private key. If that is the case then the implementation is just bad from the third-party.